# How do I make log4net.dll optional?

Tags: c#, log4net

I use log4net to implement logging in my .NET app.
However I do not want to distribute the 300kb log4net.dll for every user but instead send this dll to the user if he has problems and I want him to provide logs.

So, is it possible to make my app run whether or not the dll is there? 
Of course for logging the dll would be needed, but if no logging is needed, the app should run without the dll.

Comment: Make it a plugin. See [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/).

Comment: 300kb?   That's nothing, ship it.

Comment: @SteveWellens Nothing? The exe has just 15kb and does not need to be installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does NHibernate implement optional log4net logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015840/how-does-nhibernate-implement-optional-log4net-logging)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

First create an interfase with all your log methods:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Write(string message);
    // And much more methods.
}
```

Now create two instances, a dummy instance (lets call it `DummyLogger`), and a instance which will send its messages to Log4Net (`Log4NetLogger`).

To finish, create a factory class:

```
static public class LogFactory
{
     static public ILogger CreateLogger()
     {
          if (/*Check if Log4Net is available*/)
               return new Log4NetLogger();
          else
               return new DummyLogger();
     }
}
```

You could check if Log4Net is available by simply checking if the file is in your bin-folder. Something like:

```
File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Log4Net.dll")
```

But I can imagine that you want to do other checks, like if it exists in the GAC or whatever.

Now you can use your factory to create your logger and "write" messages to the log:

```
ILogger logger = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger();
logger.Write("I am logging something!");
```

Comment: In order for this to work you will need to load the log4net library dynamically and construct the `Log4NetLogger` object via reflection. If not, the main application will contain a static reference to the log4net.dll and refuse to start if it's not present.

Comment: @MartinStettner: I just tested it. My solution does work. A static reference will fail as soon as you call a method that will contain (not necessaril call/use) objects from the assembly that is missing. In my case the static reference will fail if one of the members of the Log4NetLogger is called, which will not happen.

Comment: How do you configure your logging?

Comment: Good question. I can imagine that Log4Net needs to be configured and in advance. If you would put the settings inside app.config then app.config would depend on the available assembies which will produce an exception. Luckily Log4Net supports a seperate XML-file which can be delivered with the exe. When the Log4Net.dll is copied into the application folder, Log4NetLogger can load and use that configuration file.

Comment: How does this make the log4net.dll optional at all?  The application is now coupled to log4net.dll and it must exist on the system for the application to run at all (needs to be able to find `Log4NetLogger` class).

Comment: @Peter: No, it does not. A "hard reference" will not cause a problem. Yes, the compiler will put all assemblies into the same folder, but Ollie can delete the Log4Net.dll before shipping it. Check out my response to MartinStettne.

Comment: Have you managed to get a working example of reading from a xml file under these circumstance? I'm asking because a while back I tried briefly (and failed) to do what the OP is asking. Defining the interface (something similar to your answer) was no problem, but once I started trying to configure it, I ended up requiring the log4net dlls.

Comment: @sgmoore: Not at this moment. This week I am free from work. But I would not load the configuration if I was sure the DLL was present. I mean: why load the configuration if there is not log4net.dll in the first place?

Comment: @MartinStettner It may come as a surprise to you, but in .net if a dependent assembly is not used it does not have to be present for the application to run, even if it is referenced in metadata.

Comment: @zespri This would really be a surprise. I just tried a quick project: One EXE and one DLL. The main program (in the exe) asks, if I want to use a class which is located in a separate DLL (like `if (response=='Y') { var c=new Class1();c.DoIt(); }`, to get the idea). I built the project, quit VisualStudio, went to the bin/Debug dir, deleted the DLL and tried to run the EXE. I immediately got a `FileNotFound` exception, stating that `ClassLibrary1.dll` couldn't be found ...

Comment: @MartinStettner: Read again my comment at the top of this answer: "A static reference will fail as soon as you call a method that will contain (not necessaril call/use) objects from the assembly that is missing." Your method contains Class1 (to be able to create it). So it will fail. Move the creation of Class1 to another method and your test will succeed. For example: `if (response=='Y') { var c=CreateNewClass1();c.DoIt(); }`

Comment: @MartinMulder Ok, you're right :) I tried it out, it works. Thanks a lot (it's never too late to learn something new :) ...)

Comment: @MartinStettner: (BTW beautiful first name) :) It was nice to be a hummble part of your learning process. Now give be a big... vote :)

Comment: @MartinMulder. I have this working now (albeit only with a test project). The mistake I was making was including a conditional call to  `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` in a method that was being run whereas, as you pointed out, I need to move that to a separate method that is only run if the log4net dlls exist.